# Its possible deploy a hybrid NEXT.js application in Azure?

Tags: azure, next.js, azure-devops, azure-webapps

I'm trying to deploy a Next.js application who uses client and server components and also serve functions, however, when I try to deploy to Azure just don't work. The closest I came was on Static web apps and the pages were bugged, next auth didn't work, etc.
Is there a way to do this correctly? I took care of the edge functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next.js hybrid support in Azure Static Web Apps is in preview. During the preview, the following features of Static Web Apps are unsupported for Next.js with server-side rendering:

- APIs using Azure Functions, Azure AppService, Azure Container Apps or Azure API Management.
- Deployment via the SWA CLI.
- Static Web Apps provided Authentication and Authorization. - Instead, you can use the Next.js [Authentication](https://nextjs.org/docs/authentication) feature.
- The `staticwebapp.config.json` file. - Features such as custom headers and routing can be controlled using the next.config.js file.
- `skip_app_build` and `skip_api_build` can't be used.
- Incremental static regeneration (ISR) does not support caching images and [on-demand revalidation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration#using-on-demand-revalidation)
- Next.js versions 13 and above have limited support for hybrid-rendering. Static HTML export is fully supported.

You can check whether your website requires features that are not currently supported. See the official doc [Deploy hybrid Next.js websites on Azure Static Web Apps (Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/deploy-nextjs-hybrid) for more detailed info.